# Data Receive Event Handler for Serial Port not Work

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm working on a project that controlling some dynamixel motors.
i have to send the information to them as hex.
its ok and i send the hexes by array of bytes with write() Function of serial ports.
but when the motors send hex information In format of bytes on serial port,
Data Receive Event Handler of serial port is never calls.
please help :(

```
 private void ComPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                int length = ComPort.BytesToRead;
                byte[] buf = new byte[length];`enter code here`
                ComPort.Read(buf, 0, length);
                //this.Invoke(new EventHandler(display));
            }
```

Comment: Make sure the length of receive data is > 0.

Comment: The problem is that ComPort_DataReceived function is not called at all

Comment: You need to register the event using "+="

Comment: Thank you But I've done that before

Comment: Do not use any handshaking (neither hardware or software).  The serial port should be set to No Parity, One stop bit,  8 bit data.  I'm assuming from your description you are able to send, the device is returning data, and the hardware cable is good (since the data was correctly sent).  I'm not sure how you determined the data was sent from device and assuming your assumptions are correct.